# cannot access service from another service from docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am having below docker-compose script

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  generator:
    image: my-registry:55000/gen:ci-8
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
  mail:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    ports: 
      - "8025:8025"
  integration:
    image: my-registry:55000/gen:integration-9
    build: .
```

from integration service, I am calling generator service as below

```
public const string GeneratorApiRoot = "http://generator:80";
var client = new HttpClient();
var sendEmail = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    RequestUri = new Uri($"{GeneratorApiRoot}/EmailRandomNames")
};

using (var response = await client.SendAsync(sendEmail))
{
   response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

I am getting status code 404 not found error msg. But when I access from host with http://localhost:8080/EmailRandomNames I am getting 200 status code.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: Are you using the integration service code to test and just replacing `generator:80` with `localhost:8080`? Or, are you using something different to test? First blush, it should work. Could it be that you're GETting the URL when testing from the host which works. Because your code is POSTing to the URL. This could explain the discrepancy.

Comment: What's the value of GeneratorApiRoot?

Comment: GeneratorApiRoot value is http://generator:80

Comment: Hi DazWilkin, I am doing post request for generator service from host with http://localhost:8080/EmailRandomNames url, and got status code 200. But from integration container service, I am accessing generator service with http://generator:80 (which I think is correct), here I am getting 404 status code from integration container service.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/EmailRandomNames is a post method. So I am doing the same post request with http://generator:80/EmailRandomNames